# WinAPI FTPGetFile Conversion From ANSI to Unicode

Tags: vba, winapi, unicode, ftp, wininet

Premise: Copying files from Linux to Windows over FTP using WinInet FtpGetFile.

Objective: The files originate as ANSI and are needed in Unicode.

Progress:
The only issue I am having is that I need LF characters from the original file to be CRLF characters in the destination file. 
I have tried:

```
Public Declare Function FtpGetFile Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FtpGetFileW" (ByVal hFTP As Long, ByVal sRemoteFile As String, ByVal sNewFile As String, ByVal bFailIfExists As Boolean, ByVal lFlagsAndAttributes As Long, ByVal lFlags As Long, ByVal lContext As Long) As Boolean
Public Sub test(hConn as Long, strSrcPath as String, strDestPath as String)
  'All code works other than the file not converting to having CR chars
  ftpGetFile(hConn, StrConv(strSrcPath, vbUnicode), StrConv(strDestPath, vbUnicode), True, 0, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

- (FAILS to convert) using the Unicode version of the `FtpGetFile` method (`Alias FtpGetFileW`), passing the arguments using `StrConv(<string>, vbUnicode)`. The files show up with only LF chars at the end of the lines.
- (WORKS, manually) copying files manually using WinSCP. It automatically makes the output files Unicode but I can't find the method/settings associated with this. I cannot use the WinSCP.dll at my work as I cannot register it.
- (WORKS, slowly) using a work-around. using the either version of the `FtpGetFile`. Opening file, reading to variable, closing file and then opening file for write, writing `Replace(variable,Chr(10),Chr(13)&Chr(10))`. Also, files appear to ~double in size.

How do I get a file using the WinAPI functions and have it convert in one shot (if possible)?

Related articles:
[Unicode turns ANSI after FTP transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483625/unicode-turns-ansi-after-ftp-transfer) 
[Writing ANSI string to Unicode file over FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496110/writing-ansi-string-to-unicode-file-over-ftp)

Source Info:
[How to Create FTP Components CodeGuru](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/vb_internet/article.php/c19511/Creating-an-FTP-Component-in-Visual-Basic.htm)
[MSDN for WinInet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385483(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: `Also, files appear to ~double in size.`
I just figured this out. Unicode (UTF16) files use about twice the number of bytes due that method of saving characters. See this post for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/700221/2497009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following appears to be working near instantaneously. If anyone has any better suggestions on how to automate this (preferably without this work-around or to make my work-around better) please provide them. Otherwise, I'll probably be choosing this as the answer in a few days. `ftpReadFile` is a custom function that uses `InternetReadFile` and spits out the entire file as a string.

```
Public Function ftpGetFileToUnicode(hConn As Long, strFromPath As String, strDestPath As String) As Boolean
  Dim hFile As Long
  Dim objFS As New FileSystemObject, objFile As TextStream

  If Not objFS.FileExists(strDestPath) Then
      Set objFile = objFS.CreateTextFile(strDestPath, ForWriting)
      objFile.Write Replace(ftpReadFile(hConn, strFromPath), Chr(10), Chr(13) & Chr(10))
      objFile.Close

      If objFS.GetFile(strDestPath).Size > 0 Then
          ftpGetFileToUnicode = True
          Exit Function
      End If
  End If

  ftpGetFileToUnicode = False
End Function
```

Note: Creates a 0 byte file if the file doesn't exist. Can easily be changed to not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I know nothing about VB. But [FtpGetFile says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384157%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it supports ASCII mode transfers, which have implicit line ending conversion:

```
ftpGetFile(hConn, StrConv(strSrcPath, vbUnicode), StrConv(strDestPath, vbUnicode),
           True, 0, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I attempted this using both `FtpGetFile` aliases and it appears to not add the carriage-return characters. I forgot to mention, in the original post, that I attempted using this flag. I am checking for characters using Notepad++ 'Show All' view option.